# Mac OS : How clean/remove the useless System Files?

Tags: macos

My Mac Book is full and I don't know why and how remove the useless files:

[image]

The grey part is "System" and I have 130.08 GB
I don't know what is this...

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple tool called **Clean My MAC**.

Download the trial version from [here](https://cleanmymac.macpaw.com/20?campaign=cmmx_search_text_brand_lowcpc_en&ci=350526486&adgroupid=23082375366&adpos=1t1&ck=cleanmymac&targetid=kwd-12573386450&match=e&gnetwork=g&creative=293719286780&placement=&placecat=&accname=cmm&gclid=EAIaIQobChMImO2Kg6rb4AIViIuzCh0hqQkjEAAYASAAEgITBPD_BwE)

Comment: Are there a free solution ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it manually. refer [here](http://osxdaily.com/2017/04/18/clean-caches-temporary-files-mac/)